# Why the intent always use FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT and FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP?

Tags: android, browser, android-intent, flags

I notice that if I click a web address in any application, there will be an `intent` sent to the browser with `FLAGS` value of `FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP`.

Is there any particular reason why we should use these two flag attributes.

It seems every intent have this two default `FLAGS` value. Can any one explain why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have more than one browser installed but you haven't selected anyone of them as default. In this situation Android will show an app picker where you can select which browser to use.

The app picker adds the two flags to make sure it's acting as an invisible middle man to make sure control goes back to the previous activity instead of going back to the app picker again for instance when using the back button or when passing a result back to the calling activity's onActivityResult().

Comment: Thanks Adam. That explains a lot!